# Overloaded method resolution bug in Powershell 4

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to call `TfvcHttpClient.GetItemsAsync()` from a Powershell script:

```
$Full = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi.VersionControlRecursionType]::Full
$None = [System.Threading.CancellationToken]::None
$Items = $Cli.GetItemsAsync($TFVCPath, $Full, $false, $null, $null, $None).GetAwaiter().GetResult()
```

In Powershell 4, it errors out:

```
##[error]System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Management.Automation.Adapter.CompareOverloadCandidates(OverloadCandidate candidate1, OverloadCandidate candidate2, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Management.Automation.Adapter.FindBestCandidate(IEnumerable`1 candidates, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Management.Automation.Adapter.FindBestCandidate(IEnumerable`1 candidates, Object[] arguments, PSMethodInvocationConstraints invocationConstraints)
   at System.Management.Automation.Adapter.FindBestMethod(MethodInformation[] methods, PSMethodInvocationConstraints invocationConstraints, Object[] arguments, String& errorId, String& errorMsg, Boolean& expandParamsOnBest)
   at System.Management.Automation.Language.PSInvokeMemberBinder.InvokeDotNetMethod(DynamicMetaObject target, DynamicMetaObject[] args, BindingRestrictions restrictions, MethodInformation[] mi, Type errorExceptionType)
   at System.Management.Automation.Language.PSInvokeMemberBinder.FallbackInvokeMember(DynamicMetaObject target, DynamicMetaObject[] args, DynamicMetaObject errorSuggestion)
   at System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject.BindInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, DynamicMetaObject[] args)
   at System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObjectBinder.Bind(Object[] args, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters, LabelTarget returnLabel)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder.BindCore[T](CallSite`1 site, Object[] args)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute7[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction``8.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
```

Looks like the logic of overload resolution is buggy. The method is indeed overloaded, but there's only one overload with 6 arguments. The other two have 7.

Powershell 4 supports omitting method parameters with default values (as long as those are `null`), so overload resolution logic still might apply. However, my invokation is not ambiguous - there's no other overload that takes a `VersionControlRecursionType` as the second parameter.

Any ideas how to work around this? Maybe there's a way to tell Powershell to call a specific overload?

They've fixed this in PS5, but still...

---

Edit: reproduced on a clean DLL. Here's the DLL code, reproducing the offending method signatures:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi
{
    public enum VersionControlRecursionType
    {
        None = 0, OneLevel = 1, OneLevelPlusNestedEmptyFolders = 4, Full = 120
    }
    public class TfvcItem { }
    public class TfvcVersionDescriptor { }

    public abstract class TfvcHttpClientBase
    {
        public TfvcHttpClientBase() { }

        public virtual Task<List<TfvcItem>> GetItemsAsync(string project, string scopePath = null, VersionControlRecursionType? recursionLevel = null, bool? includeLinks = null, TfvcVersionDescriptor versionDescriptor = null, object userState = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            return null;
        }
        public virtual Task<List<TfvcItem>> GetItemsAsync(Guid project, string scopePath = null, VersionControlRecursionType? recursionLevel = null, bool? includeLinks = null, TfvcVersionDescriptor versionDescriptor = null, object userState = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            return null;
        }
        public virtual Task<List<TfvcItem>> GetItemsAsync(string scopePath = null, VersionControlRecursionType? recursionLevel = null, bool? includeLinks = null, TfvcVersionDescriptor versionDescriptor = null, object userState = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            return null;
        }
    }


    public class TfvcHttpClient : TfvcHttpClientBase
    {
        public TfvcHttpClient() { }
    }
}
```

And here's the Powershell to demonstrate the behavior:

```
Add-Type -Path "Foo.dll"
$Cli = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi.TfvcHttpClient
$Full = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi.VersionControlRecursionType]::Full
$None = [System.Threading.CancellationToken]::None
$Items = $Cli.GetItemsAsync("", $Full, $false, $null, $null, $None)
```

---

I've caught the exception in a debugger, too. The offending method sits in `System.Management.Automation.dll`. The `candidate` arguments that describe overloaded methods contain two arrays - `arguments` and `conversionRanks`. The code expects them to have the same length, but the former has 7 elements and the latter has 6.

Comment: A way to work around this might be by calling the method through Reflection.

Comment: I'm struggling to find the doc for this method, but is it possible that one of your parameters is being cast differently to how you expect and so the wrong overload gets chosen similar to https://www.cafe-encounter.net/p2179/powershell-string-split-off-by-method-overload-error ?

Comment: The problem is not that a wrong overload is being chosen. The problem is that the very overload choosing logic within `System.Management.Automation` exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 7 parameter method overload that takes a GUID as the first parameter doesn't error out in this particular way. Powershell 4 still has a method resolution bug :)